# Deep copying a struct fetched from a smart contract (web3js) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, deep-copy, web3js

I'm trying to deep-copy in JavaScript a struct from my Solidity smart contract, which is fetched using web3js

This is how I do it:

```
 participant = await this.state.ContractInstance.methods.retrieveParticipant(0).call();
 let deepParticipant = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(participants));
```

***A) If I console.log() the participant variable, this is what I get***
[image]
***B) If I console.log() the deepParticipant variable (the deep clone) I get this***
[image]

They are not the same.

**So the question is: How do I get a perfect deep copy of it?**
I also tried cloning using Lodash and the results are no better.

Comment: Use the solidity ABI package `abi.decode()` function.  See https://medium.com/coinmonks/abi-encode-and-decode-using-solidity-2d372a03e110